# How can I multiply two 2-dim. matrices?

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation, algebra

If I have the given below matrix d1[7,7], how can I multiply d1 by d1 to get the square matrix d2=d1.d1 ?

```
nn = 6;
Table[x[i + 1] = Cos[i Pi/nn], {i, 0, nn}];
For[i = 0, i <= nn, i++,
For[j = 0, j <= nn, j++,
d1[i + 1, j + 1] = (x[i + 1] - x[j + 1])]]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `nn = 6;` ```x = Table[Cos[i \[Pi]/nn], {i, 0, nn}]```  ```(d1 = Table[
    x[[i + 1]] - x[[j + 1]], {i, 0, nn}, {j, 0, nn}]) // MatrixForm``` ; ```(d2 = d1 . d1 // N) // MatrixForm``` Other comments: 1) Mma is 1-based, not 0-based 2) Instead of `For`, `Table` can be used. 3) Enter commands in separate cells and evaluate each separately.  
 If this does not meet your needs, then please edit your question further.

Comment: You can also check matrix dimensions using ```Dimensions[d1]``` for instance.

Comment: Thanks Syed for your help and for your advance. Yes it works.

Answer (score 3):

It's faster and cleaner not to use any `For` loops and use list processing whenever possible:

```
nn = 6;
x = Cos[Subdivide[nn]*Pi]
(*    {1, Sqrt[3]/2, 1/2, 0, -1/2, -Sqrt[3]/2, -1}    *)

d1 = Outer[Subtract, x, x]
(*    {{0, 1 - Sqrt[3]/2, 1/2, 1, 3/2, 1 + Sqrt[3]/2, 2},
       {-1 + Sqrt[3]/2, 0, -(1/2) + Sqrt[3]/2, Sqrt[3]/2, 1/2 + Sqrt[3]/2, Sqrt[3], 1 + Sqrt[3]/2},
       {-1/2, 1/2 - Sqrt[3]/2, 0, 1/2, 1, 1/2 + Sqrt[3]/2, 3/2},
       {-1, -Sqrt[3]/2, -1/2, 0, 1/2, Sqrt[3]/2, 1},
       {-3/2, -1/2 - Sqrt[3]/2, -1, -1/2, 0, -1/2 + Sqrt[3]/2, 1/2},
       {-1 - Sqrt[3]/2, -Sqrt[3], -1/2 - Sqrt[3]/2, -Sqrt[3]/2, 1/2 - Sqrt[3]/2, 0, 1 - Sqrt[3]/2},
       {-2, -1 - Sqrt[3]/2, -3/2, -1, -1/2, -1 + Sqrt[3]/2, 0}}    *)

d2 = d1 . d1 // Expand
(*    {{-11, -4 - 7 Sqrt[3]/2, -15/2, -4, -1/2, -4 + 7 Sqrt[3]/2, 3},
       {-4 - 7 Sqrt[3]/2, -37/4, -4 - 7 Sqrt[3]/4, -4, -4 + 7 Sqrt[3]/4, 5/4, -4 + 7 Sqrt[3]/2},
       {-15/2, -4 - 7 Sqrt[3]/4, -23/4, -4, -9/4, -4 + 7 Sqrt[3]/4, -1/2},
       {-4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4},
       {-1/2, -4 + 7 Sqrt[3]/4, -9/4, -4, -23/4, -4 - 7 Sqrt[3]/4, -15/2},
       {-4 + 7 Sqrt[3]/2, 5/4, -4 + 7 Sqrt[3]/4, -4, -4 - 7 Sqrt[3]/4, -37/4, -4 - 7 Sqrt[3]/2},
       {3, -4 + 7 Sqrt[3]/2, -1/2, -4, -15/2, -4 - 7 Sqrt[3]/2, -11}}    *)
```

Comment: Thanks Roman but I do not understand this? I mean d1=outer[subtract....?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation of [`Outer`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Outer.html)? Combine it with the documentation of [`Subtract`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subtract.html) and you'll learn quite a bit about Mathematica's powerful list-processing functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

nn = 6;
Table[x[i + 1] = Cos[i Pi/nn], {i, 0, nn}];
For[i = 0, i <= nn, i++, 
 For[j = 0, j <= nn, j++, d1[i + 1, j + 1] = (x[i + 1] - x[j + 1])]]
```

The matrix formed by the `d1` values is

```
(mat1 = Table[d1[i, j], {i, 1, nn + 1}, {j, 1, nn + 1}]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
(mat2 = mat1 . mat1 // Simplify) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

However, the matrix `mat1` can be generated more simply with

```
mat3 = Array[Cos[(#1 - 1) Pi/nn] - Cos[(#2 - 1) Pi/nn] &, 
   {nn + 1, nn + 1}];
```

Verifying that `mat3` is identical to `mat1`

```
mat1 === mat3

(* True *)
```

In general `For` loops should be avoided.

Comment: Thanks Bob, it is very clear to me and it is very useful to my problem. I'll try to use Table instead of For-loop .